# passing a struct argument in a struct function

Tags: c, struct

I am testing passing of struct array argument in struct function **"push"** but getting an error message of

```
"passing 'shelf' (aka 'struct shelf') to the parameter of incompatible type 'shelf *' (aka 'struct shelf *');".
```

How can I fix this error? I don't know what needs to be done in order to make it work. I have declared the structs and push function in the header file.

Main purpose of this program is to access the values of **book struct** in **shelf struct**.

Here are my code snippets.

**header file**

```
#ifndef __POINTERS_H_
#define __POINTERS_H_

typedef struct book
{
    char *b_title;
    int b_pages;
}book;

typedef struct shelf
{
    char *s_title;
    int s_pages;
}shelf;

book book_details[100];
shelf shelf_item[100];

shelf push(shelf item[100]);


#endif // __POINTERS_H_
```

**c file:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "pointers.h"

int main(void)
{
    book book_details[100];
    shelf shelf_item[100];

    book_details[0].b_title = "c++";
    book_details[0].b_pages = 200;

    push(shelf_item[0]);
    printf("Shelf Item's title is: %s\n", shelf_item[0].s_title);
    printf("Shelf Item's title is: %i\n", shelf_item[0].s_pages);

    return 0;
}

shelf push(shelf item[100])
{
    strcpy(item[0].s_title, book_details[0].b_title);
    item[0].s_pages = book_details[0].b_pages;

    return item[0];
}
```

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: `__POINTERS_H_` identifiers with double underscores are reserved by C standard. Don't use them in your code.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I have modified the question. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @KamilCuk I haven't used double underscores in my code. Maybe you are referring to is the header in the header file and that's pre-defined.

Comment: This is C. You can't return a shelf, only a shelf*. And you can't pass an array with 100 elements to a function. Only a pointer to an array. And the message is clear: You can't pass a shelf to a function because it is a struct. You can only pass shelf* to a function.

Comment: @reichhart: you *can* pass structs as parameters and return them from functions, the reason why it doesn't work here is that the function is declared to accept an array of structs. Returning small structs from functions is not an issue in C.

Comment: Yes, I checked even old c89 standard and it was even valid there. But as embedded developer I avoid it. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1.** The arguments do not match.

`shelf item[100]` when passed as an argument will decay to `shelf *item`.

As you are passing a `shelf` object as an argument(the first element of the array), that won't work.

---

**2.** Note that this statement:

```
book_details[0].b_title = "c++"
```

Leads to undefined behavior, `b_title` struct member is an uninitialized pointer, as is `s_title`, you cannot store anything in it until it points to a valid memory location, alternatively you can use a char array:

```
char b_title[100];
```

And

```
char s_title[100];
```

To assign a string to it you then need to use `strcpy` or a similar method.

---

**3.** There is also the fact that you declare `book book_details[100];` and `shelf shelf_item[100];` twice, at global scope and again in `main`.

---

Assuming global `shelf_item` and `book_detais` arrays you can do something like:

**Header**

```
typedef struct book {
    char b_title[100]; //b_title as char array, alternatively you can allocate memory
    int b_pages;
}book;

typedef struct shelf {
    char s_title[100]; //s_title as char array
    int s_pages;
}shelf;

book book_details[100];
shelf shelf_item[100];

void push(); //as shelf is global there is no need to pass it as an argument
```

**C file**

```
int main(void) {
    strcpy(book_details[0].b_title ,"c++"); //strcpy
    book_details[0].b_pages = 200;

    push();

    printf("Shelf Item's title is: %s\n", shelf_item[0].s_title);
    printf("Shelf Item's title is: %i\n", shelf_item[0].s_pages);
    return 0;
}

void push() {
    strcpy(shelf_item[0].s_title, book_details[0].b_title);
    shelf_item[0].s_pages = book_details[0].b_pages;
}
```

---

Assuming local `shelf_item` and `book_detais` arrays you can do something like:

**Header**

```
#define SIZE 100

typedef struct book {
    char *b_title;
    int b_pages;
}book;

typedef struct shelf {
    char *s_title;
    int s_pages;
}shelf;

void push(book *b, shelf *s); //pass both arrays as arguments
```

**C file**

```
int main(void) {

    book book_details[SIZE];
    shelf shelf_item[SIZE];

    book_details[0].b_title = malloc(SIZE); //allocate memory for b_title
 
    if(book_details[0].b_title == NULL){ /*deal with error*/}

    strcpy(book_details[0].b_title ,"c++");
    book_details[0].b_pages = 200;

    push(book_details, shelf_item);

    printf("Shelf Item's title is: %s\n", shelf_item[0].s_title);
    printf("Shelf Item's title is: %i\n", shelf_item[0].s_pages);
    return 0;
}

void push(book *b, shelf *s) {

    s[0].s_title =  malloc(SIZE); //allocate memory for s_title
    if(s[0].s_title == NULL){ /*deal with error*/}

    strcpy(s[0].s_title, b[0].b_title);
    s[0].s_pages = b[0].b_pages;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that it is a good thing to provide a complete solution for the home exercise? ;-)

Comment: @reichhart, maybe a got carried away, I still think these are just relatively small fixes to the OP original program, I wouldn't call it a solution to the exercise.

Comment: @anastaciu thanks for explaining each and everything in much much detail. It's not an assignment, I am new at learning c language and was practicing different ways of using structs. I studied different books but the way you explained is so comprehensive. You can write your own book and i ll be the first one to buy it.

Comment: @OwaisQayum, I appreciate your words, I'll consider your advice, at least one copy will be sold I guess :)

Comment: @anastaciu I just wanted to prevent that you do even more. ;-) Nevermind, you got my upvote.

Comment: @reichhart, I'll keep that in mind, I trust you'll buy my book too ;)

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues. Here's the first one which causes the issue:

```
push(shelf_item[0]);
```

The error message is that you are passing `shelf` while `shelf *` is expected (array). Simply pass the address of the item (the start of the array): `&shelf_item[0]`

The prototype

```
shelf push(shelf item[100]);
```

does not make any sense if you just want to push one item.

Also

```
book book_details[100];
shelf shelf_item[100];
```

are declared twice.

And it is "bad style" (TM) if a function got only one argument passed but uses a hidden/global variable to also work on.

And your print statement does not print the values of the returned item.

Comment: I have made many mistakes and after reading your feedback things are much clearer now.